# why img:hover doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem on `img:hover`

Here's my jsbin: http://jsbin.com/bereputu/1/edit

My problem is when I put my mouse over the "home" or "contact", the image that I want to replace the original appears a little under than I expected.

Here's my code:

```html
<html>

<head>
    <title>UltraLotus</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <img src="images/header.png">
        </div>
        <center>
        <div class="nav">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/home.jpg"></a>
                    <a href="contact.html>"><img src="images/contact2.jpg"></a>
        </div>
        </center>
        <div class="page">
            <p></p>
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```css
body {
    background-image: url("images/bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}

.container {
    min-height: 100%;
}

.header {
    background-color:#1a1a1a;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
}

.header img {
    position: relative;
    margin-top:-30px;
}

.nav {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    top: -15px;
    background-image: url("images/nav.jpg");
}

.nav img {
    position:relative;
    margin-top:13px;
}

.nav a:first-child:hover {
    position:relative;
    background-image: url('images/home.jpg');
}

.nav a:nth-child(2):hover {
    position:relative;
    background-image: url('images/contact.jpg');
}
.page {
    padding-top:5px;
    top:150px;
    padding-bottom:70px;
}

.footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:70px;
    background-image: url("images/footer.jpg");
}
```

Comment: If you have a question like this, it'd be helpful (and nice) if you remove all irrelevant html and css (which is about 97% of the code). Only post [*relevant* code](http://sscce.org).

Comment: I'm new on this zone, tell me how to simplify my codes or use codes easier and remove all irrelevant codes?

Comment: I just did. Did you read the link I posted? In addition, the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) has some good info, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're looking to accomplish with the `:hover` styling, but it's replacing a totally different image than the one you're using in your original nav element.

For easier debugging, if you open up the chrome developer tools, you can force a hover state so you can look at all the applied css rules:

[image: screenshot]

You'll notice that you're giving your `a` element a `background-image` on hover, but it's contents still contains an `img` element.  Thus the double styling.

**Note 1**: Since they're both the same, you really don't even need the hover styling at all.

**Note 2**: This does not seem worth pulling in an image to me.  You should be able to accomplish this exact style with native html an css.  They render far quicker, they're much easier to download, they're much better for screen readers, they have much cleaner and clearer content, and they extend and adapt much easier.  I'd skip the images altogether and go html/css for this.

---

Here's a little CSS to get your started:

```css
.nav a  {
  color: grey;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 0px;
  border-top-left-radius: 7px;
  border-top-right-radius: 7px;
}

/* I even added in a little hover effect */
.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #2C2C2C;
}
```

Here's your full site design without any images (except your logo):

#### http://jsbin.com/bereputu/2/

You can get much more sophisticated but I would avoid imaging out your design as much as possible.  If you're doing web dev, learn CSS

Comment: it's true, i tried to do it on HTML and CSS, but still... i got a few errors so i tried to do on photoshop because I find it a lot easier but after all it isnt